# What are the consequences of passing an object to a method within the same object?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I've stumbled upon code project that is organized something like the following:

```
Namespace TheProject
{
    public class SerialPortManager
    {
        public class RingBuffer
        {
            // Clears the buffer
            public void Clear(SerialPortManager theManager)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of a method call:

```
spm.RingBuffer.Clear(spm);
```

I'm surprised this code doesn't result in the program crashing. What are some of the implications of the code being organized this way? Can this result in memory leaks? What other problems might I be looking at? Or is this a legitimate but quirky way to organize code?

Comment: why do nest a class within another class. It is legitimate. I am just trying to understanding the rationale.

Comment: If I had written this, I would have separated RingBuffer out, and have it be a separate class (i.e. not nested within SerialPortManager) In this case, RingBuffer is only used within SerialPortManager, so I think the person that coded it did it for their convenience.

Answer (score 5):

Not at all. It's perfectly legit. `RingBuffer` is a class that is part of `SeriarPortManager`... but it needs to know which `SerialPortManager` to use to clear the proper buffer.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I really appreciate it. Is this analogous to a recursive function, when a function calls itself? In other words, is  it common for an object (lets call it foo) to reference itself within a method (i.e. foo.bar(foo) ?)

Comment: @Locklier There is no recursivity in here. Putting a class definition within a class is a way of organizing your structure in a logical order. It's a way of saying that `RingBuffer` is a working part of a `SerialPortManager`.

Comment: I understand that RingBuffer can be part of SerialPortManager, but why is it that I can pass an object to itself?

Comment: @Locklier Ok... I think you don't understand the difference between a class and an object. A class is a definition, like a blueprint of a chair, while an object, is the chair itself. You give the blueprint to the computer and it generates the object. When you pass an object to `RingBuffer`, you pass the real unique instance of that object and not its definition. It's like saying `Sit on THAT chair`.

Comment: Right, BUT in the example I gave: spm.RingBuffer.Clear(spm), "spm" is an object. So, spm.RingBuffer.clear(spm) passes spm to the clear method, that method that resides within RingBuffer, but is part of the instance of spm. So what I'm asking, is how can a chair sit on iself?                                                          Chair chair = new Chair();                                                      chair.sit(chair); // How does a chair need itself in order to sit?

Comment: @Locklier Are you sure there isn't a `static` keyword somewhere? Maybe in front of the method or in front of the `RingBuffer` class?

Comment: Thanks for being so patient with me. Some of the instances of SerialPortManager (e.g. "spm") are static, but not all of them. Neither SerialPortManager or RingBuffer or PurgeBuffer are static.

Comment: @Locklier How about methods? Does the `Clear` method is static? Can you update your post with the real code?

Comment: Clear isn't static. I'm afraid I can't post the real code - What I did post is a pretty realistic summary of it though. No statics to be found.

Comment: What I can think of is that maybe a property is named `RingBuffer` too. It could be a singleton pattern. But I think the important part is, no, it's not illegal and it can be quite useful too.

Answer (score 1):

`RingBuffer` is not part of the **object**, it's part of the **class**. That is, it's not tied to the current instance at all, so there are no implications related to that. In fact, the method call you posted is not valid, because you can only access `RingBuffer` from the `SerialPortManager` class, not from an instance of it.

The only effect that defining a class as nested has is the way it's accessed. When a nested class is `public`, the containing class is just a namespace for it, but it could also be `private` or `protected` if it should only be accessible from the containing class or its inheritors.